# Is there a way to make a lines formed image look smoother in imshow/pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data file which contains some physical property defined on several contour-like lines (the data is represented in the figures I attached). I used **pcolormesh** to plot those curves (Figure 1).

But the resulting lines are to rough and I want to smoothen them. Using *shading* I get rather blurred than smoothened version of my image (Figure 2).

I also tried **imshow** function with various interpolation options, but since my data is structured in the way that the meaningful values are surrounded with zeros, interpolation doesn't help a lot.

Is there any way to make the smoothened version of the curve, which will still look more or less sharp?

**pcolormesh plot with no shading applied**
[image: pcolormesh plot with no shading applied]

**pcolormesh plot with shading**
[image: pcolormesh plot with shading]

Comment: I think you have to evaluate your function(s) on more sample points i.e. make the grid you're evaluating on finer.

Comment: The figures are not displayed, maybe edit?

Comment: I added the links to the figures. Apparently as a new user here I cannot make the figures as display items.

Comment: Judging from the images, I would say, that Thomas Lang is right. Either you have enough data points to make it sharp or you have to interpolate, which makes it a bit blurry

Comment: I don't think you *should* do anything. Your data set is coarse; suggesting it is not by artificially smoothing the image comes down to manipulating that same data.